# Dúvida no Toast.makeText(this, ...)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Este é o mesmo código de uma dúvida anterior, porém agora a minha pergunta é outra.

No `Toast.makeTest(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);` dá o seguinte erro na hora de compilar, acredito que por causa do contexto desse **this**:

> ```
> error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
> ```

> ```
> error: no suitable method found for makeText(Validacao,String,int)
> method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; Validacao cannot be converted to Context)
> method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; Validacao cannot be converted to Context)*
> ```

As minhas perguntas são: Como ficaria o código para usar o `Toast` no método `static isValid()`? Será que não posso usar o **Toast** em métodos **static**?

Já tentei pôr `getApplicationContext()`, assim:

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Porém deu erro. Já tentei pôr `Validacao.java`, mas também dá erro:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Validacao.java, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Abaixo o código da classe **Validacao.java** com um método construtor **Validacao()** e um método estático **isValid()** usando o **Toast**, que quando compilados, geram os erros acima mencionados:

```
package br.com.joao.coursera.calculadora;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Validacao {
    public  Validacao() {  }

    public static boolean isValid(EditText et, String msg) {
            if (et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece pois `this` não existe em objetos/métodos estáticos, porém há outro erro no código. Segue explicação abaixo.

---

Para utilizar o `Toast.makeText` é necessário passar o `context` como parâmetro. Acontece que `this` é uma referência da classe e não existe em objetos/métodos estáticos.

Quando você utiliza `Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);` em uma *Activity* o código irá funcionar sem problemas, isso porque, diferente da sua classe `Validacao`, a classe `Activity` estende a classe `Context`.

Agora que já sabemos que é necessário um objeto do tipo `Context`, vamos para o próximo passo.

Quando objetos do tipo `EditText`, `ImageView` etc. São criados, automaticamente é adicionado o contexto da *activity* nos objetos ([ver na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#EditText(android.content.Context))), portanto todos os esses objetos trazem consigo o `context` de onde foi criado. Para capturá-lo, basta utilizar o método `object.getContext()`.

Ou seja, ao invés de utilizar `this` ou `getApplicationContext()` no método `isValid`, utilize `et.getContext()`, por exemplo:

```
public class Validation {

    public static boolean isValid(EditText et, String msg) {
            if (et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(et.getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
            }

            return !et.getText().toString().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, funcionou!